# how to create application folder in android

Tags: android

I am creating application folder on first activity on onCreate() Method but folder is not creating.here is the code

```
 if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
        File fil = new File(this.getFilesDir().getPath()+File.separator+"MyContactsBackUp");
        fil.mkdirs();

} else {
    File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"MyContactsBackUp");
    directory.mkdirs();
}
```

Comment: have you declare write external permission in manifest ?

Comment: @ChiragRaval: yes sir

Comment: @ChiragRaval is there any issue with my code

Comment: One possibly helpful similar issue I originally ran into was that I was trying to look at /sdcard in DDMS--but it really writes to /mnt/sdcard

Comment: Do you run while your phone plug in the computer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),File.separator+"MyContactsBackUp/");
f.mkdirs();
```

or for internal memory of application instead of write hardcore sting use.

```
File f = new File(getCacheDir(),File.separator+"MyContactsBackUp/");
f.mkdirs();
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this code

```
if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
    android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

       File podcastFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator
                                             + getString(R.string.app_name));
} else {
            /* save the folder in internal memory of phone */

    File podcastFolder = new File("/data/data/" + getPackageName()
                    + File.separator + getString(R.string.app_name));

}
```